# Convert array of objects to array of arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

```
var json = [{one: "text1", two: "text2", three: 3, four: 4},
            {one: "text3", two: "text4", three: 5, four: 6},
            {one: "text5", two: "text7", three: 8, four: 9}]
```

How can I convert the array of objects above into an array of arrays below?

```
var array = [["text1", "text2", 3, 4], 
             ["text3", "text4", 5, 6], 
             ["text5", "text7", 8, 9]]
```

Is there an ES2015 function to help convert it easily? If not a for loop might do.

Comment: What you have is an array of objects, not JSON.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `map` and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
let array = json.map(obj => Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: `Object.values` is not ES6 though.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) directly as callback, which is available with ES 2017

```js
var array = [{ one: "text1", two: "text2", three: 3, four: 4 }, { one: "text3", two: "text4", three: 5, four: 6 }, { one: "text5", two: "text7", three: 8, four: 9 }],
    result = array.map(Object.values);
                
console.log(result);
```

A classical approach

```js
var array = [{ one: "text1", two: "text2", three: 3, four: 4 }, { one: "text3", two: "text4", three: 5, four: 6 }, { one: "text5", two: "text7", three: 8, four: 9 }],
    result = array.map(o => Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k]));
                
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Same here: `Object.values` is not ES6. Probably fine to use, but since the OP only mentions ES2015, worth to point out at least.

Comment: Object.values is even more pretty worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In case you need to explicitly specify order, you can destructure and map each item:

```
var array = json.map(({ one, two, three, four }) => ([one, two, three, four]))
```

This would also work for unordered keys in your original object, e.g.:

```
var json = [{ two: "text2", one: "text1", three: 3, four: 4 },
            { one: "text3", three: 5, two: "text4", four: 6 },
            { four: 9, two: "text7", three: 8, one: "text5" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code snippet -

```
function convertObjCollToArrColl(json) {
    for (var i = 0, array = []; i < json.length; i++) {
        var el = json[i];
        array.push([el.one, el.two, el.three, el.four]);
    }
    
    return array;
}

convertObjCollToArrColl(json);
```