# Convert array of objects into array of key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert an array of object which looks like

```
var someJsonObj = [
  {id: 0, name: "name", property: "value", otherproperties: "othervalues"},
  {id: 1, name: "name1", property: "value1", otherproperties: "othervalues1"},
  {id: 2, name: "name2", property: "value2", otherproperties: "othervalues2"}
];
```

to

```
var someArray = [
  [0,"name","value","othervalues"],
  [1,"name1","value1","othervalues1"],
  [2,"name2","value2","othervalues2"]
]
```

using `.push` but what I'm getting are three empty arrays or one array of first values like `[0,1,2]`

```
        var someArray=[];
        for(var i=0;i<someJsonObj.length;i++){
            someArray.push(someJsonObj[i].val);
        }
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array of objects to array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143390/convert-array-of-objects-to-array-of-arrays)

Comment: @Xufox hard to find that one as no one voted for that question :|

Comment: @JackTheKnife It was at +1/-1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Object.values()` in es6:

```
  const someArray = someJsonObj.map( obj => Object.values(obj) );
```

Comment: If you want to guarantee order, use `.map(({id, name, property, otherproperties}) => [id, name, property, otherproperties])` instead.

Comment: Also, if you don't follow @Xufox advise, I would provide `Object.values` as is: `someJsonObj.map(Object.values)` :P

Comment: Does that actually work? I tend to worry about problems with binding `this` when using Object.whatever()

Comment: Somehow I'm getting a string instead of array of values. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805989/array-of-objects-to-array-of-array-came-as-a-string