# Array of objects to array of array came as a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have JSON object `oAtt` declared as

`var oAtt = MessageStore.message().attachments();`

`MessageStore.message()` is declared in the code available here: https://github.com/RainLoop/rainloop-webmail/blob/master/dev/Model/Message.js

When I output it to the console `oArr` came as  `[object Object],[object Object]`. After `stringify` it came as:

```
 var oAtt = [
    {"sModelName":"AttachmentModel","disposables":[],"mimeType":"application/pdf","fileName":"sample.pdf","fileNameExt":"pdf","fileType":"pdf","description":null,"estimatedSize":19333,"friendlySize":"19KB","isInline":false,"isLinked":false,"isThumbnail":false,"cid":"","cidWithOutTags":"","contentLocation":"","download":"zyfTZvzczVW6cqlcsIrm3ycmY5soz3DzK5sZhjnSOwaW0wnwGwHtqBvPeo8nVpiWD4yKVIPvAPauJHZufHGRG0Eb4MRmBpkGlvsDGP-gz3CnVp4GorN_xXCI0Gkd2I93IySKMy5iXRt-wML9wxLwTZcrOMLyPp-Kr6b0GlzlHuvk3RqEXRqSlCQTX5piRO6AaRYeMKeq8PSJcId1grMYzFpCnjVSoW_Zj7yTGAsy-D_mzFoCmBdksCweEqPdGhFYFkukblXzaZiTSNGTj1xYOvMIN4XXUZtU0EAPoQ9EFxfPWY_-1Siyge0Gks2zbGs3myxXJg..","folder":"INBOX","uid":"22","mimeIndex":"2","framed":false},
    {"sModelName":"AttachmentModel","disposables":[],"mimeType":"image/jpeg","fileName":"test4.jpg","fileNameExt":"jpg","fileType":"image","description":null,"estimatedSize":26326,"friendlySize":"26KB","isInline":false,"isLinked":false,"isThumbnail":true,"cid":"","cidWithOutTags":"","contentLocation":"","download":"BN0gFmNTTOarHTn7bDrdaLxLQ-HmO36mmT8av0rwGMsO9XeBlK7OWBq4uiR5N3RkgjXBwwDtOcLBTPIx-354pFHsV2BigaNfpvFG7XlkFYyCsOwGQcNS2pR_U53ISNCnDV-bZYNjl6dc-XAPb71qOkkxn-XxWCtfqJl5ngPPQ67owcZUUfIv9ddSsGyX5PhMljxyMq6f_Cz6dp07Xeaex89ED35VTqyJe4C1MyAxq92fJlxBstcj7dM12YbRJzzWeS_B9t6g48mwh-0am6c28uxPAGYc_EP4C3VweITw7Q5uhTtNmycMksTu4CIVepYn","folder":"INBOX","uid":"22","mimeIndex":"3","framed":false}
    ]
```

When I have tried to convert that object to an array of values array it came as

> `sample.pdf,test4.jpg`

using code below:

```
var aAtt = oAtt.map(({fileName}) => [fileName]);
```

When I will access it directly as `oAtt[0].fileName` I'm getting file name value. Also when I run it off the main code (only declared `oAtt` and `map` code line) it works as should.

Any clue what can be wrong?

Comment: FYI There isn't a single syllable of JSON in your question. JSON is a *string notation* that can be parsed into an object, while you already have a concrete object.

Comment: @PeterB I have re-phrased my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clue why `.map` is not working when used in the main code but I have ended up with a code below

```
var aAtt = new Array();

for(var i=0;i<oAtt.length;i++)
{
   aAtt[i] = new Array();

   aAtt[i].push(oAtt[i].fileName);
   aAtt[i].push(oAtt[i].mimeType);
   aAtt[i].push(oAtt[i].download);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your problem. What is `oArr` tho? You are talking about `oAtt` and `aAtt` in your code.

```js
var oAtt = [{
    "sModelName": "AttachmentModel",
    "disposables": [],
    "mimeType": "application/pdf",
    "fileName": "sample.pdf",
    "fileNameExt": "pdf",
    "fileType": "pdf",
    "description": null,
    "estimatedSize": 19333,
    "friendlySize": "19KB",
    "isInline": false,
    "isLinked": false,
    "isThumbnail": false,
    "cid": "",
    "cidWithOutTags": "",
    "contentLocation": "",
    "download": "zyfTZvzczVW6cqlcsIrm3ycmY5soz3DzK5sZhjnSOwaW0wnwGwHtqBvPeo8nVpiWD4yKVIPvAPauJHZufHGRG0Eb4MRmBpkGlvsDGP-gz3CnVp4GorN_xXCI0Gkd2I93IySKMy5iXRt-wML9wxLwTZcrOMLyPp-Kr6b0GlzlHuvk3RqEXRqSlCQTX5piRO6AaRYeMKeq8PSJcId1grMYzFpCnjVSoW_Zj7yTGAsy-D_mzFoCmBdksCweEqPdGhFYFkukblXzaZiTSNGTj1xYOvMIN4XXUZtU0EAPoQ9EFxfPWY_-1Siyge0Gks2zbGs3myxXJg..",
    "folder": "INBOX",
    "uid": "22",
    "mimeIndex": "2",
    "framed": false
  },
  {
    "sModelName": "AttachmentModel",
    "disposables": [],
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "fileName": "test4.jpg",
    "fileNameExt": "jpg",
    "fileType": "image",
    "description": null,
    "estimatedSize": 26326,
    "friendlySize": "26KB",
    "isInline": false,
    "isLinked": false,
    "isThumbnail": true,
    "cid": "",
    "cidWithOutTags": "",
    "contentLocation": "",
    "download": "BN0gFmNTTOarHTn7bDrdaLxLQ-HmO36mmT8av0rwGMsO9XeBlK7OWBq4uiR5N3RkgjXBwwDtOcLBTPIx-354pFHsV2BigaNfpvFG7XlkFYyCsOwGQcNS2pR_U53ISNCnDV-bZYNjl6dc-XAPb71qOkkxn-XxWCtfqJl5ngPPQ67owcZUUfIv9ddSsGyX5PhMljxyMq6f_Cz6dp07Xeaex89ED35VTqyJe4C1MyAxq92fJlxBstcj7dM12YbRJzzWeS_B9t6g48mwh-0am6c28uxPAGYc_EP4C3VweITw7Q5uhTtNmycMksTu4CIVepYn",
    "folder": "INBOX",
    "uid": "22",
    "mimeIndex": "3",
    "framed": false
  }
];

var aAtt = oAtt.map(({fileName}) => [fileName]);

console.log(oAtt);
console.log(aAtt);
```

Comment: When I run it as standalone it works as should but not in the main code.

Comment: Insert your whole code including the `oArr definition` please

Comment: I can't see anything you posted here inside of your github. Sorry but can't reproduce, you gotta target a specific code before to give it to us. Perfect would be a snippet reproducing the problem. Good luck