# How to map json object to array list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi I have json object data from ajax as below.

```
var history= [
    { date: '12/1/2011', open: 3, high: 5,low: 2, close:4 },
    { date: '12/2/2011', open: 4, high: 6,low: 3, close:5 },
    { date: '12/3/2011', open: 3, high: 5,low: 2, close:3 }
];
```

I would like to map only stock data to array list as below.

```
[
  [3,5,2,4],
  [4,6,3,5],
  [3,5,2,3]
]
```

Prefer use the map method (data.map(function(a)). Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50143412/5648954) from the duplicate

Comment: I’m being pedantic here. That’s not JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem like you already know : )

```js
var history= [
    { date: '12/1/2011', open: 3, high: 5,low: 2, close:4 },
    { date: '12/2/2011', open: 4, high: 6,low: 3, close:5 },
    { date: '12/3/2011', open: 3, high: 5,low: 2, close:3 }
];

const parseData = i => [i.open, i.high, i.low, i.close];
const res = history.map(parseData);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use [`history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) as the name of your variable.

> The [`Window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) read-only property returns a reference to the [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) object, which provides an interface for manipulating the browser session history (pages visited in the tab or frame that the current page is loaded in).

You can try with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
var historyList= [
    { date: '12/1/2011', open: 3, high: 5,low: 2, close:4 },
    { date: '12/2/2011', open: 4, high: 6,low: 3, close:5 },
    { date: '12/3/2011', open: 3, high: 5,low: 2, close:3 }
];

historyList = historyList.map(o => Object.values(o).slice(1));
console.log(historyList);
```